# How do I properly handle AddressNotFound error from maxminddb::geoip2 in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a small piece of code that I need to fix and don't know much about Rust.

When I execute the following, it fail for certains ip values.

```
let city: geoip2::City = georeader.lookup(ip).unwrap();
let c_name = city.city
                .and_then(|cy| cy.names)
                .and_then(|n| n.get("en")
                .map(String::from));

let loc = city.location.unwrap();
let lat = loc.latitude.unwrap();
let lon = loc.longitude.unwrap();
```

It fails with an AddressNotFound exception.

I tried to return a default value with

```
let city: geoip2::City = georeader.lookup(ip).unwrap_or_else(|err| geoip2::City::default(););
```

with it does not work nor address fully my problem.

In the end, I would like to catch AddressNotFound and set

```
let c_name = "unknown"
let loc = None
let lat = ""
let lon = ""
```

and use the actual value when available

```
let c_name = city.city
                .and_then(|cy| cy.names)
                .and_then(|n| n.get("en")
                .map(String::from));
let loc = city.location.unwrap();
...
```

when the city is available.

I just don't know how to do such a thing in Rust. Could anyone point me to an quick example or helpme with that particular case?

**Updated**:

I took comments and tried the following:

```
let city: std::result::Result<Option<geoip2::City>, maxminddb::MaxMindDBError> = georeader.lookup(ip);
let (c_name, lat, lon) = match city {
  Ok(Some(city)) => (
    city.city.and_then(|cy| cy.names)
             .and_then(|n| n.get("en")
             .map(String::from)),
    city.location.unwrap().latitude.unwrap(),
    city.location.unwrap().longitude.unwrap()
   ),
   _ => (Some("unknown".to_owned()), 0.0_f64, 0.0_f64),
 };
```

I know have to find a way to use multiple city.location attributes in this context. I currently get this error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `city.location`
  --> src/main.rs:93:15
   |
92 |               city.location.unwrap().latitude.unwrap(),
   |               ------------- value moved here
93 |               city.location.unwrap().longitude.unwrap()
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
   |
```

Comment: Maybe the examples here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html help you figuring out to know what to do. Let me know if you have further questions after reading this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can go like this, though I'm typing it from my head, so expect that it doesn't work right away

```
let (c_name, loc, lat, lon) = match city.city {
  Ok(Some(names)) => (
    names.get("en").to_string(), 
    city.location, 
    <something>, 
    <something>,
  ),
  _ => ("unknown", None, "", ""),
}
```

**Update:**
First of all, entities like `City` and `Location` support `Clone` trait, so you can clone then instead of moving, but there's another dirty way using `.as_ref()` like that:

```
let city: std::result::Result<Option<geoip2::City>, maxminddb::MaxMindDBError> = georeader.lookup(ip);
let (c_name, lat, lon) = match city {
  Ok(Some(city)) => (
    city.city.and_then(|cy| cy.names)
             .and_then(|n| n.get("en")
             .map(String::from)),
    city.location.as_ref().unwrap().latitude.unwrap(),
    city.location.as_ref().unwrap().longitude.unwrap()
   ),
   _ => (Some("unknown".to_owned()), 0.0_f64, 0.0_f64),
 };
```